# Retrofit - Too many follow-up requests: 21

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp, cookiemanager

I'm using retrofit to make requests.

I've got following error:

> java.net.ProtocolException: Too many follow-up requests: 21

The code is like below:

```
private OkHttpClient httpClient;
private CookieManager cookieManager;

public <S> S createCookieService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
    httpClient.interceptors().clear();
    httpClient.setCookieHandler(cookieManager);
    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit
            .Builder()
            .client(httpClient)
            .baseUrl(url)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient).build();

    return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
}
```

And then I'm making requests:

example:

1) login

```
 @POST("/login")
 Call<User> login();
```

2) some request:

```
@GET("/request")
Call<PojoPojo> getPojo();
```

And I'm getting this error too many follow-up requests: 21.

Please help.

Comment: did you find any solution for this yet?

Comment: Yes, i did but some very important dude from facebook (Martijn Pieters) decided to delete link to answer. Good luck.

Comment: Why don't you just put up the answer here? Isn't that the whole point of SO?

Comment: This may happen due to an error on your Server side

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Jake Wharton wrote:

> This gets thrown (by OkHttp, not Retrofit) when there are more than 20
>   redirects when calling an endpoint. Usually this indicates a redirect
>   cycle between two endpoints. Both Chrome and Firefox will also stop
>   loading the request after this many redirects and fail the request.
>
> You need to consult with your server team or endpoint documentation to
>   ensure you are passing the correct data directly to the endpoint you
>   want to call. No action for Retrofit to take here.

And rest of the thread is there:
https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1561

Comment: This solution might be useful if you want to reduce the number of retries :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29456534/handling-authentication-in-okhttp

Answer (score 7):

This also happen's when the token's header's key already exists and instead of replacing it with the new token as shown below:

```
response.request.newBuilder()
                .header("Authorization", token)
                .build()
```

you add the new token(a single key can have many values in the headers), what's common in a lot of questions is add the token like this:

```
response.request.newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Authorization", token)
                .build()
```

This will result the request failing again(401) and you'll end up in a loop.

TL;DR: The correct way of **setting** a new token is:

```
response.request.newBuilder()
                    .header("Authorization", token)
                    .build()
```

Answer (score 5):

As a workaround, it is possible to use:

```
new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .followRedirects(false)
    .followSslRedirects(false)
```

Nice to take a look at [okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/okhttp_3.12.x/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/internal/http/RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java) class source code.

I'm using version **3.12.0** of OkHttp.

Answer (score 4):

For me the issue was: the request url was starting with `"/"`.
Replace url `@GET("/request")` with `@GET("request")`

- also the base url of the api should end with `"/"`
- if using an `Authorization` header check if you need to set the value as `"Bearer " + token` instead

using retrofit 2.4.0 version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
    <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

In okHttpClient,in the interceptor if your using authenticator, remove that authenticator.
It Sets the authenticator used to respond to challenges from origin servers.
It Uses [proxyAuthenticator] to set the authenticator for proxy servers.

Answer (score 0):

> In my case it was happening because of the cookie in header was expired.
> It is clear that we need to fix this in server side code but in case we can't change server side code we can use this workaround.

**Following is the workaround which worked for me**

```
catch (ProtocolException e) {
        
        Timber.w(e);
        if (e.getMessage().contains("Too many follow-up requests")) {
            doSynchronousLogin();

            Request.Builder builder = chain.request().newBuilder();
            builder.addHeader("Cookie", dataManager.getCookie());
            Timber.w("Request processed after auto-login");
            return chain.proceed(builder.build());
        }
    }
```

*Above code is added in a retrofit interceptor*