# Fabric crashlytics with Firebase unable to upload crash

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

I'm just trying to migrate **Fabric Crashlytics** with **Firebase**, so I just followed the guide [https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started](http://guide)

Everything compiles and the app can be launched. So I want to simulate a crash with `Crashlytics.getInstance().crash();` as I already used before.

The app crashes as expected, but the crash is not uploaded to firebase and I have this strange stack:

```
E/Fabric: Error performing auto configuration.
                                               io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest$HttpRequestException: java.net.ProtocolException: Too many follow-up requests: 21
                                                   at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.code(HttpRequest.java:1355)
                                                   at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.AbstractAppSpiCall.invoke(AbstractAppSpiCall.java:86)
                                                   at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.UpdateAppSpiCall.invoke(UpdateAppSpiCall.java:29)
                                                   at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.performUpdateApp(Onboarding.java:204)
                                                   at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.performUpdateApp(Onboarding.java:194)
                                                   at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.performAutoConfigure(Onboarding.java:175)
                                                   at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.doInBackground(Onboarding.java:112)
                                                   at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.doInBackground(Onboarding.java:45)
                                                   at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:63)
                                                   at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:28)
                                                   at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:311)
                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
                                                Caused by: java.net.ProtocolException: Too many follow-up requests: 21
                                                   at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:451)
                                                   at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:567)
                                                   at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
                                                   at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
```

Anyone already had encountered this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrofit - Too many follow-up requests: 21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35132330/retrofit-too-many-follow-up-requests-21)

Comment: Thanks. Are you still running into this?

Comment: I have to create the fabric.properties file and put the api key to make it working

Comment: @ToddBurner do we still need to add the api key even if we migrated to firebase?

Comment: @ToddBurner up?

Answer (score 2):

This can happen when you strip the API key from Fabric when migrating from Fabric to Firebase Crashlytics, which is not currently supported. When migrating, keep your API key in your project.