# android volley basic request wont work for Special WebSite

Tags: android, jsoup, android-volley

**Volley:**
try to get respone from a url with Volley Lib in android
its ok with google.com or other site but this website return error

```
url = http://nobat.larums.ac.ir/QueueWeb/Home/Login
```

**My Code:**

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        String url ="http://nobat.larums.ac.ir/QueueWeb/Home/Login";

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                        textView.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                textView.setText("That didn't work!");
                Log.d("Volley error: ",error.toString());
            }
        });
        queue.add(stringRequest);
```

**Manifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**Logcat:**

```
[OkHttp] sendRequest>>
I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
D/Volley error:: com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.ProtocolException: Too many follow-up requests: 21
```

**Jsoup:**
Try Connect url with Jsoup lib and good work.

```
Document htmlDocument = Jsoup.connect("http://nobat.larums.ac.ir/QueueWeb/Home/Login").get();
```

Whats the problem with this site?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrofit - Too many follow-up requests: 21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35132330/retrofit-too-many-follow-up-requests-21)

Comment: no,try with cookie and header respone but didnt work. this basic volley request work for all website just this url ...